# How can I reduce the amount of particle effects on the screen?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I play TF2 on a laptop and I get about 15-20 fps out of it. It's very inconsistent however, and it can jump to 60 in one sitting, then drop to 1 extremely quickly.

I know that there are a lot of particle effects within TF2 (Healing, bullets, fire, unusuals, etc.).  Are there any settings in-game and modifiable by configs that can give me the minimum particles needed to run TF2, yet somehow increasing performance?

Comment: Have you tried using a maxframes config, such as [Chris' configs](http://fakkelbrigade.eu/chris/configs/) or [TF2mate](http://clugu.com/tf2mate/)?

Comment: I've tried using those, they only marginally inrease my fps.  I was only aware that the config got rid of certain things (made textures worse, got rid of useless details, etc.)

Comment: Is this the settings decided by the game itself?

Comment: Techinically yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken straight from the [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Multiplayer_options):

> **Multiplayer Decal Limit**
>
> The maximum number of decals that can exist at once. Decals are used
>   for visual effects like bullet impacts. Higher numbers will result in
>   more persistent decals, at the expense of performance.

There is a command that represents the Multiplayer Decal Limit, noted by the command `mp_decals x` with *x* denoting the amount of decals you want visible in game.

Since decals are responsible for showing sprays, bullet holes, and other particle effects in game, reducing *x* will in turn lower the amount of particle effects. *X* can be a number from `0 - 200.00`.

If you'd like to have some particle effects (to still show bullet holes, useful for learning recoil patterns and such), an advisable amount is `mp_decals 9`, which is enough for seeing the Scattergun's spread without sacrificing any performance. In Chris' words (creator of Chris' configs)

```
maxframes.cfg

mp_decals 1 // `9' is a good value to still see the spread pattern from a
            // scattergun without any real performance loss.
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no in-game way to alter particle systems aside from disabling those marked as weather (this is in advanced options). You need to create or find/download particle effect mods (which may or may not work on servers of various `sv_pure` settings) that reduce particle count/complexity.

Comment: There sure is, I've used `mp_decals` command for years.

Comment: @user598527 I was under the impression that *decals* (bullet holes, explosion soot, blood spatters) and *particles* (fire, healbeams, crit bolts) are completely different things, and mp_decals only affects the former.